# Преимущества связки Apache + PHP + MySql

Tags: apache, php, mysql

В чем преимущества этой связки, и почему большинство пользуется `PHP` + `apache`? И отдельно, чем хорош Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Потому, что есть почти на любом хостинге и просто/быстро настраивается. Из-за второго она есть почти на всех хостингах.
2. Производительность для подавляющего большинства сайтов удовлетворительная.

Еще нужны причины? Мне - нет.

Answer (score 5):

Это работает.

Comment: Ты умудрился сказать двумя словами то, что я намолотил несколькими предложениями.  
Народ: флэшмоб, давайте заплюсуем алиенатора?

Comment: @alienator, и я же не скажу на защите проэкта "It's work" :)

Comment: @Expert, неправильно перевел. По-русски сервер пишет "Ура, заработало!"  
Точнее, перевел правильно, но вся соль потерялась.

Comment: > @alienator, и я же не скажу на защите проэкта "It's work" :)

Полностью согласен, "It's work" говорить на защите проэкта не стоит. Нужно говорить "It works" :)

Comment: ))))

Comment: @Expert, ну не всегда же надо переводить %)